# entry process in cpanel is always full

Tags: php, process, cpanel

I have a server in name.com.
I suffered from a problem that my server gives me this problem resource limit and I found that this is because of entry process is full 20/20.

I solved all problems appeared in error logs but still suffer from this problem.
does this problem occur duo to I am using many php coded in a page like:

```
<option value="none" selected>
    <?php echo $country["country"] ?>
</option>

<option value="AF">             
    <?php echo $country["Afghanistan"] ?>
</option>

<option value="ZA">             
    <?php echo $country["South Africa"] ?>
</option>

<option value="AX">             
    <?php echo $country["Åland Islands"] ?>
</option>

<option value="AL">             
    <?php echo $country["Albania"] ?>
</option>

<option value="DZ">             
    <?php echo $country["Algeria"] ?>
</option>

<option value="DE">             
    <?php echo $country["Germany"] ?>
</option>

<option value="AD">             
    <?php echo $country["Andorra"] ?>
</option>

<option value="AO">             
   <?php echo $country["Angola"] ?>
</option>

<option value="AI">             
   <?php echo $country["Anguilla"] ?>
</option>

<option value="AQ">             
   <?php echo $country["Antarctic"] ?>
</option>

<option value="AG">             
   <?php echo $country["Antigua and Barbuda"] ?>
</option>

<option value="SA">             
   <?php echo $country["Saudi Arabia"] ?>
</option>

<option value="AR">             
   <?php echo $country["Argentina"] ?>
</option>

<option value="AM">             
   <?php echo $country["Armenia"] ?>
</option>

<option value="AW">             
   <?php echo $country["Aruba"] ?>
</option>

<option value="AU">             
   <?php echo $country["Australia"] ?>
</option>

<option value="AT">             
   <?php echo $country["Austria"] ?>
</option>

<option value="AZ">             
   <?php echo $country["Azerbaijan"] ?>
</option>

<option value="BS">             
   <?php echo $country["Bahamas"] ?>
</option>

<option value="BH">             
   <?php echo $country["Bahrain"] ?>
</option>

<option value="BD">             
   <?php echo $country["Bangladesh"] ?>
</option>

<option value="BB">             
   <?php echo $country["Barbados"] ?>
</option>
```

And the last code is repeated to 200 times to cover all countries that I get their name from array called `$country`.

Because I found this message after I used this code

and if php codes is not the problem what makes the processes maxed fast

Answer (score 1):

Try to loop through your array ($arr):

```php
<?php
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    echo $value;
}
?>
```

Comment: Ok i know that but what is the reason for this problem entry process is full in my cpanel

Comment: I do not use files that are deleted after a time,could overloaded php codes produce this problem , do you think that?